# Prove uniform convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Assume functions $f_n: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ are meeting given conditions:

- $f_n$ are continuous
- for each $n$ there exists limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f_n(x) = g_n$
- for each $x \in [0, \infty)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $f_n(x) \geq f_{n+1}(x)$
- for each $x \in [0, \infty)$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = 0$
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n = 0$
  Show that sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: From the conditions, you may argue that $f_n$ have a maximum for each $n$. Try considering the sequence $a_n=\text{max}(f_n)$, which is clearly decreasing. Since $f_n$ are all positive, you just need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ in order to show uniform convergence to $0$. Dini's theorem might be useful.

Comment: @JohannesAgerskov how do you know $f_n$ have a maximum for each $n$?

Comment: Well actually it was wrong of me to say that $f_n$ has a maximum, I guess I was a little fast on the trigger there. But it is true that $f_n$ is bounded and thus you may use $a_n=\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}(f_n(x))$. That $f_n$ is bounded may be seen by the following. Since $f_n$ are continuous they each have a maximum on compact sets. Now you may for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ choose $N_n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n(x)<g_n+1$ for $x>N_n$ (this is since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f_n(x)=g_n$). But then you have that $f(x)\leq\max(\{g_n+1,\max_{x\in[0,N_n]}(f_n(x))\})$, i.e. $f_n$ is bounded.